# Inserting into a component list within v-for cause all remaining recreateed

Tags: vuejs2

I meet a problem when creating a page content editor with Vue#2.1.6. I use Vue dynamic component to handle each article. When I insert a new article into the v-for list, all remaining articles got reset to their initial states. Here is the example 
https://jsfiddle.net/3jowy381/

```
Vue.component('type-a', {
    template: '<div class="style-a" @click="ready">{{context.name}} prepared: {{prepared}}</div>',
    props: ['context'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            prepared: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ready: function () {
            this.prepared = true;
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('type-b', {
    template: '<div class="style-b" @click="ready">{{context.name}} prepared: {{prepared}}</div>',
    props: ['context'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            prepared: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ready: function () {
            this.prepared = true;
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('type-c', {
    template: '<div class="style-c" @click="ready">{{context.name}} prepared: {{prepared}}</div>',
    props: ['context'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            prepared: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ready: function () {
            this.prepared = true;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        position: 0,
        modules: [
            {context: {name: 'article-init-a'}, type: 'type-a'},
            {context: {name: 'article-init-b'}, type: 'type-b'},
            {context: {name: 'article-init-c'}, type: 'type-c'}
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        insertA: function () {
            this.modules.splice(this.position, 0, {context: {name: 'new-article-a'}, type: 'type-a'})
        },
        insertB: function () {
            this.modules.splice(this.position, 0, {context: {name: 'new-article-b'}, type: 'type-b'})
        },
        insertC: function () {
            this.modules.splice(this.position, 0, {context: {name: 'new-article-c'}, type: 'type-c'})
        }
    }
})
```

You can click articles to set them prepared and insert a new one beyond. All articles below the new become unprepared automatically. Vue seems to recreate them. Any way to make a walkaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are adding a new  `context` in `modules`, it is re-rendering all the articles in the `modules` array, and it initialises all those components again, resetting the `ready` variable to false.

This is evident, by putting a [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) lifecycle hook in one of the element.

One solution can be to move `prepared` property to context itself, as it looks like a property of an article, so it can be placed alongside name of article. Assuming this I have modified you fiddler, please [check](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/3jowy381/1/).

```
new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        position: 0,
        modules: [
            {context: {name: 'article-init-a', prepared: false}, type: 'type-a'},
            {context: {name: 'article-init-b', prepared: false}, type: 'type-b'},
            {context: {name: 'article-init-c', prepared: false}, type: 'type-c'}
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        insertA: function () {
            this.modules.splice(this.position, 0, {context: {name: 'new-article-a', prepared: false}, type: 'type-a', prepared: false})
        },
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: It's ok to bind a state on the context, however, there are many of them for each type of module.  It is bad to manage such a huge context since some of those state are actually contents like article text, customized color, not system state

Comment: It seems this is the only way in this context.